# Sharepoint Document ID in PDF Document Properties

Tags: 2010, pdf

I am trying to automatically add the SharePoint Document ID and version value to the Document Properties Custom tab. I am currently manually entering it and would like it added automatically when i create the pdf. Is this workflow possible? I am not talking about adding document id to the item in SharePoint, I am aware that is automatic etc. This is within the PDF document properties so when it's emailed it has the document id/version to reference back to. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to a SharePoint Designer workflow? Do you have any software development abilities (this will require it). Would you be open to a non programming solution that adds the document ID as a watermark to the PDF file?